# Elixir - how to use a default function parameter that isn't in the last position?

Tags: elixir

Consider this simple function:

```
def myfun(first \\ :a, middle \\ :b, last \\ :c) do
  {first, middle, last}
end
```

I want to pass that function specific values for first and last params, and have it infer the middle param.  I expected something like this might work:

```
{:foo, :b, :baz} = myfun(:foo, _, :baz)
```

But it doesn't.

What's the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish that. Underscore might be used only in matches (and in raw AST, but that’s out of scope here.) Declare two different functions or use named parameters aka `Keyword`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Aleksei Matiushkin mentioned in the comment, using `Keyword` might be a better option when all arguments are optional. It would look something like this:

```
defmodule Fun do
  def myfun(options \\ []) do
    first = Keyword.get(options, :first, :a)
    second = Keyword.get(options, :second, :b)
    third = Keyword.get(options, :third, :c)

    {first, second, third}
  end
end

Fun.myfun(first: 1, third: 3) # => {1, :b, 3}
Fun.myfun(second: 2) # => {:a, 2, :c}
Fun.myfun() # => {:a, :b, :c}
```

Comment: `[first: :a, second: :b, third: :c] |> Enum.map(fn {k, d} -> Keyword.get(options, k, d) end) |> List.to_tuple()` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, No, I don't think so.  No one would ever write that in place of Pawel's simple code because your code makes the same three function calls that Pawel's code does but then it adds other unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @7stud I would suggest you read about DRY principle and why it should be used everywhere. Also, the code above does not add any “other unnecessary stuff.”